# server send me(client) same data twice

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm practising socket programming in c#. I just connect server and receiving text. the problem is that for example, if I connect and disconnect from server 5 times and connect again (which is 6), server send me text 6 times when I receive data from server.

I'm connecting server with this method:

```
public void ConnectToServer(string host, int ip)
{
    try
    {
        _socket.Connect(host, ip);
        StartReceive();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

after connect I get what I want. When I want to disconnect using this method :

```
public void DisconnectFromServer()
{
    _socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
    _socket.Disconnect(true);
}
```

after disconnect, sometimes I reconnect server using ConnectToServer(..) method. When I receive data from the server, server send same data to me twice.

my socket is this :

```
private Socket _socket = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
```

What am I missing ? how to disconnect from server ? or server has problems ?

any advice ?

Comment: How about sharing the code that sends data?

Comment: I'm connecting over internet. I have just ip and port.

Comment: if I restart debugging its not happen.

Comment: What you describe is not how TCP works. TCP connections are unique, they don't receive data from other connections. Unless there is a logic bug in your `StartReceive` code that is duplicating received data, the only other way you could be getting data from earlier connections is if that is what the server is sending to you each time you reconnect. For I stance, if the server is caching data intended for your IP,keeps the data fester you disconnect, and then resends the cached data after you reconnect from the same IP.  Use a packet sniffer to verify exactly what the server is actually sending.

Comment: Could you please add the code of `StartReceive()` to your question?

Comment: Problem is fixed. The problem was in the server side. Don't know what he did but problem is gone. I did not change my code. thanks for your helps.